# In Nightwatch , How to call a command in test that exists in the "section"?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I am using nightwatch to write my tests. In my page object i have "section". That section have commands but when I call the commands in the test, it returns "section is not a function". please find my page object and test below.

```
Page Object
sections:{
    Profile:{
        myprofile:'#myprofile',
        elements:{
            firstName:{
                selector:'//a [contains(text(),\'firstName\')]',
                locateStrategy:'xpath'
            }
        },
        commands:[{
            clickRedeem(){
                return this
                    .click('@myprofile')
            },
            clickMerchandise(){
                return this
                    .click('@firstName')
            }
        }]

    }
},
```

In test I am calling the command like this

```
 this.profileTest.section('@myprofile').clickProfile(); but its returning  
 this.profileTest.section is not a function
```

I tried as you mentioned. please find the details below.

```
    redeemMenu:{
    selector:'#myprofile',
    elements:{
       merchandiseMenu:{
            selector:'//a [contains(text(),\'Merchandise\')]',
            locateStrategy:'xpath'
        },
    },
    commands:[{
        clickRedeem(){
            return this
                .waitForElementVisible('@redeemMenu')
                .click('@redeemMenu')
        },
        clickMerchandise(){
            return this
                .waitForElementVisible('@merchandiseMenu')
                .click('@merchandiseMenu')
        },


    }]

},



test

var profileSection = await this.profileTest.section.redeemMenu 
profileSection.clickRedeem()


Error: Element "redeemMenu" was not found in "redeemMenu". Available 
elements: merchandiseMenu
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors:

1. **You used wrong property** and should change

   ```
   myprofile:'#myprofile'
   ```

   to

   ```
   selector: '#myprofile'
   ```
2. **You used the wrong selector**

   ```
   var profileSection = this.profileTest.section.redeemMenu
   ```
3. To use command :

   ```
   profileSection.clickRedeem()
   ```

Comment: I tried with the way you mentioned. When I run the test, its returning an error saying that it cannot find the selector i used for the section. please find the details in the main post.

Comment: for clickRedeem() you can just do this.profileTest.clickRedeem();

Comment: I tried as you mentioned. Its returning the following.                                                          'TypeError: this.profileTest.clickRedeem is not a function
   - writing an ES6 async test case? - keep in mind that commands return a Promise;
   - writing unit tests? - make sure to specify "unit_tests_mode=true" in your config.'